# my apostrophe turns into ‚Äô

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, apostrophe

i'm trying to send the iOS device name along with the deviceToken to my server in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken.. my device has an apostrophe in it and the request string shows as ....&name=John+Doe‚Äôs+iPhone ...
I've tried replacing "'" with "" and "‚Äô" with "" .. but neither fix it.. i assume i need to convert the encoding?

```
NSString *string = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
output-> John Doe‚Äôs iPhone
```

**EDIT**

output is from
    NSLog(string);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use `NSLog` with a user-provided string like that.  `NSLog` expects a format string for its first argument.  If it's something containing a format specifier, it will probably crash your application, and may expose a security hole if provided by an untrusted source.

Your encoding issue appears to be a bug in LLDB.  Switching to GDB fixes the problem.

Comment: thanks.. that worked!.. don't know I would've ever stumbled upon that.. and I was just using NSLog for troubleshooting here.. but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Wait, you're doing `NSLog(string)`? You need `NSLog(@"%@", string)`

Comment: that gives an error "Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'const char *' "

Comment: yes i suppose i was being lazy.. NSLog(@"%@", string) still outputs John Doe‚Äôs iPhone